# odoo 8 website javascript python

Tags: javascript, python, web, odoo-8

I'm a beginner with odoo and I must create a website.
I want use JavaScript on my website. But when I read many forums, I don't understand how I can use JavaScript.

Actually, I have a checkbox on my website and I would like when you tick a checkbox, my result would change automatically.
I don't know if it's possible with Odoo.